# Nasm change value in array

Tags: nasm

I have function that take two value `(int * a , int * b)`
So a goes to RDI and b to RSI.
My `b` is an array and one of the taskes is to change `b[1]` value.

So in my asm file i try to do this as with any simple array

```
mov [rsi+1*4] ,5
```

An here i got 'operation size not specified' error

Comment: How is nasm supposed to know if `5` is a byte, a word, a dword or a qword?  That's the 'size' it is looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get this error because Nasm doesn't know which size has place in memory where you try to write `5`. It seems that you try to work with value of C `int` type. Specify operand size in your `mov` statement.

For example if on your platform `int` C type is 4 byte sized, you should write `mov dword [rsi+1*4] ,5`